# Scale a Netty UDP server

Tags: netty

We implement an UDP server using Netty. This server needs process *huge* number, say millions, of UDP requests per second. We're wondering what the best strategy for the Netty UDP server to support such workload: increase the buffer size of the UDP server, setup a "cluster" of the UDP server, or something else?

(If a cluster is the solution, what's recommended to be the load balancer of the cluster?)

Answer (score 1):

As there is not much detail given its hard to give a lot of advice. That said generally speaking I would create multiple `EpollDatagramChannel` instances and bind these to the same `InetSocketAddress` by using `EpollChannelOptions.SO_REUSEPORT`. This will allow the kernel to load-balance the packets across file descriptions and so threads.

Something like this:

```
EventLoopGroup group = new EpollEventLoopGroup(numThreads);
Bootstrap bs = new Bootstrap();
bs.channel(EpollDatagramChannel.class)
  .channelOption(EpollChannelOption.SO_REUSEPORT)
  .handler(yourHandler)....

bs.localAddress(yourLocalAddressAndPort);

List<Channel> channels = new ArrayList<>();
for (int num = 0; num < numThreads; num++) {
    channels.add(bs.bind().sync().channel());
}

...
...
```

Comment: Would your answer resolve my issue of *millions* request per second by *one* server? By the way, by millions, it means tens or hundreds millions. So you think it is a *programming* issue?